# Why does sign-out from Leaderboard result in an application crash?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

When I've signed-out from within the Leaderboards by accessing settings, and when I attempt to sign back in, the application crashes. It seems that `GameHelper` does not register this sign-out.

How does one fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a similar issue that was raised on the [github repo](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/121). Its indicated there that its working as intended.

> When you start a GPGS activity, you have to start it with `startActivityForResult`. If the user clicks on sign-out, the `GoogleApiClient` is NOT disconnected - it's just in a "signed out" state. The `onActivityResult` here will return a status `RECONNECT_REQUIRED`. At this point, the developer should reconnect their client, and life goes on as expected.

Try to modify the RECONNECT_REQUIRED condition block to disconnect, or create a way to handle it specific to your usecase (log-in page?).